# Image reflection using imagemagick command line?

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

**Original Image**

[image]

```
convert image.jpg -scale 310x496\! scaled.png
convert scaled.png +clone -flip -crop 310x150 -compose Dst -composite  out/shadow.png
convert -size 310x150 -alpha set gradient:rgba\(255,0,255,0.6\)-rgba\(255,255,0,0.50\) out/grad.png
convert out/shadow.png out/grad.png -compose Dst_Out  -composite out/shadow_gradiented.png
convert shadow_gradiented.png out/shadowed.png -append out/final.png
```

**I am getting following output**

[image]

**But I want my output to be like following.**

[image]

What am i doing wrong? Suggest me.

**Additional:**
Is there any way I can make all in one command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not certain what you are trying to achieve, but this might get you started:

```
convert wolf.jpg -scale 310x496\! \
   \( +clone -flip -crop x150+0+0\! -alpha set -channel A -fx "0.6" \) -append result.png
```

[image]

---

If you want the alpha tailing off, try a formula that is a function of `j` (the distance from the top of the reflection) and `h` (the total height of the reflection).

```
convert wolf.jpg -scale 310x496\! \
   \( +clone -flip -crop x150+0+0\! -alpha set -channel A -fx "0.8-(0.6*j)/h" \) -append result.png
```

---

If you want the code to be a bit more generic, and less dependent on actual sizes, you could change the height of the reflection to, say 1/4, of the height of the original (note the change from `convert` to `magick`)

```
magick wolf.jpg -scale 310x496\! \
   \( +clone -flip -crop "x%[fx:h/4]+0+0\!" -alpha set -channel A -fx "0.8-(0.6*j)/h" \) -append result.png
```

Comment: Pleasure! I have added a little extra in case you want the alpha to tail off towards the bottom.

Comment: I have installed imagemagick in ubuntu. But it shows magick command not found. Why is that? convert is working fine.

Comment: The `magick` command is an improved replacement for `convert` but which only appeared in v7 of ImageMagick so you'd need to be on at least that version.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44128387/imagemagick-command-geometry-not-working - Can you help me with this.