# Imagemagick command geometry not working

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am having image1.jpg with the size of 350x500 and another image2.png ( 350x150 ) with gradient effects like shadow. I need to apply the shadow to image1.jpg in its bottom. But geometry doesn't work for me.

```
convert -extent 600x700\! image1.jpg \( image2.png -geometry +0+500 \) -composite final.png
```

I hope the geometry will position an image at the point I have given, If I am right, geometry is not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not certain what you are trying to achieve, but is this close:

```
convert xc:red[350x500] -extent 600x700\! xc:blue[350x150] -geometry +80+300 -composite result.png
```

[image]

Maybe you have some left-over paging info in your PNG file, you can remove it by adding `+repage` immediately after loading it:

```
convert ... ... image.png +repage ...
```

You can identify it like this:

[image]

Comment: convert xc:red[350x500] -extent 600x700\! -geometry +100+100 xc:blue[350x150] -geometry +80+300 -composite result.png --- I am trying to set geometry for first image and its not working.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps what you want is to use combinations of -gravity and -geometry in ImageMagick. For example

```
convert -size 600x700 xc:white xc:red[350x500] -geometry +50+50 -composite xc:blue[350x150] -gravity south -geometry +0+20 -composite -bordercolor black -border 1 result1.png
```

[image]

Here I have created your white image of size 600x700 and composited your red image 50 pixels in x and y down and to the right. Then I set the gravity to south and composite the blue image up 20 pixels from the bottom. I have added black border so it is easier to see the image boundary.

Alternately, you can add an offset to -extent with negative values to shift the white relative to the red. That way you do not have to create the first white image and composite the red onto it.

```
convert xc:red[350x500] -extent "600x700-50-50" xc:blue[350x150] -gravity south -geometry +0+20 -composite -bordercolor black -border 1 result2.png
```

[image]

But unfortunately, the offset on the extent seems to trim (the height of) the red image. So I do not think this is an effective solution.